# Valuing a Bonsai

Tags: bonsai

I’ve recently gotten a few bonsais I’d like to now sell. How do I got about valuing them to know what to ask for?

Here’s what they look like:
[image: mytrees]

I know the one on the left is ~2.5 years old, and the one on the right is considerably older, though I don’t know how old.

Comment: I would train the one on the right first into shape before selling it, having a better shape will increase the price for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value is going to be in the eye of the buyer.

I look at the pot, plant type, age and shape.

The left plant, being so young and not much real shape to it would get no more than a few $ from me.

The right plant, can't quite tell from the base trunk what is going on, but as presented, also not much value there either.

Comment: Thanks Flowerbug.